# Electrical Component Degradation Over Time

Tags: components

I have a brand new 5-Disk CD Carousel Player.  It was never used except for initial test about 20 years ago.  It was stored in original box with all packing materials including desiccant in basement.  I have not tested it yet.

Question:  What, if any, electrical components could be compromised by this lengthy storage? Or, could the unit operate "good as new"?   Thanks.

Comment: Apart from capacitors (as in Colin's answer), metals on surfaces or in connectors could have corroded (maybe because the package included dessicant that will not be the case). Internal batteries could have leaked. Plastics inside the mechanisms could have become brittle.

Comment: The silica gel desiccant will have gone off after about a year or two so, your package storage is compromised and your product's "reliability" is under threat. Anything might happen in a basement. This basically means that your question is somewhat pointless and is soliciting for opinions. Opinions are ruled off topic for this site hence I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wet electrolytic capacitors age, they lose capacitance, and any batteries used for real time clocks, or retaining information in RAM may have become leaky.

The unit could operate as well as new, or may not, depending on how much it's worth, and how much it means to you, I would be tempted to try it and see.